# Getting gps not working

Tags: android, gps

can someone explain me why my code is not working?
I tried to get gps as easy as posible. Debugger didn t find any error but when I run it, it just doesn t work. I can get GPS enabled and GPS disabled msges but never gps latitude and longtitude..

here s code:

```
public class getgps extends AppCompatActivity {

double longtitude;
double latitude;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_getgps);
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, mlocListener);


}


public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {

        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        longtitude = loc.getLongitude();
        String Text = "My current location is: " +
                "Latitude = " + latitude +
                "Longitude = " + longtitude;
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                Text,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                "Gps Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {



        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                "GPS Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), + latitude +" ",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_getgps, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Thanks for ideas. ^_-

Comment: Try changing `mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, mlocListener);` to `mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);`..also make sure that you should test the app in open sky for the first time.

Comment: I tried also with 0, 0 but it wasn t working. Now I tried it in open sky as you told me ^^ and it worked. but its interesting because for example google maps or waze have no problem even in the hause.  thanks

Comment: Oh great..i'll add that as my answer..could you please mark the answer as accepted if it really helped you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, Please make sure that you **test the application under open sky** atleast once. Only then the GPS gets fixed and you get a GPS data.